# What is the reason for fetching data even though the cacheTime remains when using React state as a query key in react-query?

Tags: reactjs, react-query, tanstackreact-query

What is the reason for fetching data even though the cacheTime remains when using React state as a query key in react-query?

```
  const [value, setValue] = useState(3336);
  const { isLoading: postLoading, data: postData, refetch } = useQuery(
    ["post", "post", { value }],
    () => getPost(value + ""),
    {
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
      refetchOnMount: false,
      retry: 0,
    }
  );
```

value: 3336 -> 4444 -> 3336

I have a cache about `value: 3336`.  also cacheTime remains but it is refetching data...

What is reason?

```
  const { id } = useParams();

  const { isLoading: postLoading, data: postData } = useQuery(
    ["post", "post", { id }],
    () => getPost(id + ""),
    {
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false, // 포커스 toggle 시 refetch
      refetchOnMount: false, // 컴포넌트 리랜더링시 refetch
      retry: 0,
    }
  );
```

It's is working well. I confuse....

Answer (score 2):

when the QueryKey changes, react query will observe a new cache entry, which is likely empty initially. So, it has to fetch data for that key. This is expected and a good thing.

If you want to avoid the loading state and keep data on screen from the old key, you can pass `keepPreviousData: true` to your Query.